# How can I set a specific center for Google Map?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a specific location that I want to be the center of my map.
I have the following code:

```
theMap.moveCamera(
              CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                         new LatLng(
                                   location.getLatitude(),
                                   location.getLongitude()), 17.0f
                         )
              )  
);  
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                                 .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));  
markerOptions.icon(createIcon());  
theMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

Problem: The map shows the location and the icon but I want the icon to be in the center of the map. Now the icon is within the boundaries but not in the center.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you share your `createIcon()` method and post a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)

you can easily use `setCenter` function, like

> theMap.setCenter(markerOptions.position);

or `panto` to display smoothly, like

> theMap.panTo(markerOptions.position);

[Here](http://codepen.io/Lincecum/pen/mELkJP) is a example I wrote show whats different between.